# jQuery passing arguments to callback not working on .keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple autocomplete feature as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#search-field').keyup(function(e) {
        ajaxAutocomplete(e);
    });
});


function ajaxAutocomplete(e) {
    var hash_tag = $.trim($(this).val());

    $.ajax({
        url     : 'autocomplete.php',
        method  : 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data    : {tag : hash_tag}
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        if (response) {
            $('.datalistPlaceholder').html(response).show();
        } else {
            $('.datalistPlaceholder').hide();
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert('Something went wrong');
    });
}
```

I am trying to use the event object in `ajaxAutocomplete` function as described by jQuery:  https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

The above set up does not work and returns this: `jquery.js:7328 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

This does work after removing the callback from above:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#search-field').keyup(ajaxAutocomplete);
});

function ajaxAutocomplete() {
    var hash_tag = $.trim($(this).val());

    $.ajax({
        url     : 'autocomplete.php',
        method  : 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data    : {tag : hash_tag}
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        if (response) {
            $('.datalistPlaceholder').html(response).show();
        } else {
            $('.datalistPlaceholder').hide();
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert('Something went wrong');
    });
}
```

Comment: Where have you used `event` ?

Comment: It's not working because you loose the value of `this` in the anonymous function. Is that the only question, why `this` is not the element when you wrap it in an anonymous function ?

Answer (score 1):

After combining Rory's answer above and reading about [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) from MDN I came up with the following that works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#search-field').keyup(function(e) {
        ajaxAutocomplete.call(this, e);
    });
});

function ajaxAutocomplete(e) {
    console.log(e)
    var hash_tag = $.trim($(this).val());

    $.ajax({
        url     : 'autocomplete.php',
        method  : 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data    : {tag : hash_tag}
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        if (response) {
            $('.datalistPlaceholder').html(response).show();
        } else {
            $('.datalistPlaceholder').hide();
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert('Something went wrong');
    });
}
```

Result on typing 'a':

`j…y.Event {originalEvent: KeyboardEvent, type: "keyup", timeStamp: 1292.2500000000002, jQuery21406902543265129839: true, keyCode: 65…}`

Comment: The OP doesn't use the event in his code anywhere though, hence I omitted it

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first example is because you wrap the call to `ajaxAutocomplete()` in an anonymous function which means that you lose the reference of `this` within your called function (it will point to the `window` instead of the `#search-field` element). This in turn means that `$(this).val()` returns nothing - hence the error coming from jQuery.

You need to either use `.call(this)` when calling your function to maintain the scope of `this` within the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#search-field').keyup(function(e) {
        ajaxAutocomplete.call(this);
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ok9tvya0/)

Alternatively you can use your second method which passes the `ajaxAutocomplete` function reference to the event handler which then maintains scope:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#search-field').keyup(ajaxAutocomplete);
});
```

Personally I prefer the latter approach for its brevity.

Comment: Thanks @rory! Nevertheless with `.call(this)` I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @RobertRocha apologies - I made an error in the `call()` code. My answer should work now.

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function, the context `this` gets lost. If you use the callback directly, the context is available.